# after changing to port 80 I cannot access tomcat home page

Tags: unix, tomcat

I need to access tomcat web manager, but how to do it if server_ip:8080 is no longer valid?
application is deployed as root, so I get to my application when trying server_ip:80

Comment: As stated in the answer, that way is much better, though I did that with `mod_jk` (to host my website from home for free)a long time back, I had written those [steps](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/webpages/configureht.html), just in case someone wanted to do that for educational purposes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do not run a server as root. Use Commons Deamon or Apache Web Server with `mod_proxy`.